# How to integrate html5 and iphone applications?

Tags: iphone

As we all know that html5 has introduced lots of new features.

How can html5 be integrated to an iphone application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PhoneGap as the wrapper.  PhoneGap basically takes your HTML5 based web page and makes it into an iPhone app that can be submitted to the AppStore. They also provide a set of Javascript libraries which expose the iPhones features to your app, so you can use location et al within JavaScript.

Comment: Thanx Moo...It is really a nice package